# How many text/plain and text/html parts can an email have?

Tags: python, email

I am trying to write a generic parser function for emails in python. I want this function to be able to fetch all of the plain-text and all of the html of any email.

```
def parse(msg):
    """function accepts an email.message_from_bytes object."""
    
    text = None
    html = None

    for p in msg.walk():
        if p.get_content_type() == 'text/plain':
            text = p.get_payload()

        elif p.get_content_type() == 'text/html':
            html = p.get_payload()

    return text, html
```

My question is: Can an email have multiple text/plain or parts or text/html parts? In the above function I am only parsing one instance of each. Do I need to be prepared for instances where there are more than one text/plain part or html part?

Comment: You can define `text` and `html` as `list` and append each part to list. E.g. `text_parts = []`, `text_parts.append(p.get_payload())`.

Comment: But I want to know if I need to. Its not easy to read through the RFC 2822 docs.

Comment: I'm not big specialist but as far as I can remember, I've had email with several blocks, but I'm not sure was it `html` or `multipart`..

Comment: I don't think there's any limit. But if it's multipart/alternative, it would be unusual to have multiple parts with the same MIME type -- the usual reason for this type is to select different formats.

Comment: See https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html section 7.2.3 it's not very complicated.

Comment: If it's multipart/mixed, there's no reason why you couldn't have multiple segments with the same type. It could alternate between text and images, for instance.